# Get binary file data sent from postman in net core web api?

Tags: asp.net-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

How to read the video file sent from the postman in body binary...
Content-Type : video/mp4
Content-Range: bytes 0-5119999/33230845
Content-Length: 5120000

```
 IFormFile file;

            using (var sr = new BufferedStream(Request.Body))
            {
                var byteArray = await sr.ReadAllBytes();
                var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                file = new FormFile(stream, 0, byteArray.Length, "testName", "testFileName");

                string path = $"C:\\Projects\\vid{uploadRequest.BlockId}.mp4";
                using FileStream str = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
                str.Position = 0;
                await stream.CopyToAsync(str);
            }

public static async Task<byte[]> ReadAllBytes(this Stream instream)
        {
            if (instream is MemoryStream)
                return ((MemoryStream)instream).ToArray();

            await using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            await instream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
```

When I save this file into **C** Disk and open it, says that: item is unplayable...

[image]
[image]

Comment: I know that I can use formfile but in this case, it is important to be on binary...

Comment: `When I save this file into C Disk and open it, says that: item is unplayable` Please check if that video itself is corrupt, and if the original video file can be played with that  media player.

Comment: Yeah of course...

Comment: Request Body is file chunk

Comment: If you upload a smaller video, does it work well?

Comment: no, it does not

Comment: I have uploaded pictures you can see

Comment: Try to remove the request headers that you set, then test if it can work.

Comment: You already receive the bytes through `Request.Body`. You can save them to disk directly, there's no point in the rest of the code. You could. write `Request.Body.CopyTo(str)`. All. you'd need is `using var fs=File.Create(somePath);Request.Body.CopyTo(fs);`

Comment: Actually i dont neet to save into file it was only for test purpose...

Comment: but I will try if it works